# char buffers comparison

Tags: comparison, char, buffer

i have two char buffers which i am trying to compare parts of them. i am having a weird problem. i have the following code:

```
char buffer1[50], buffer2[60]; 
// Get buffer1 and buffer2 from the network by reading sockets
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    if(buffer1[15+i] != buffer2[25+i])
    {
        printf("%c", buffer1[15+i]);
        printf("%c", buffer2[25+i]);
        printf("%02x", (unsigned char)buffer1[15+i]);
        printf("%02x", (unsigned char)buffer2[25+i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

The above code is a simplified version of my actual code which I didnt copy-paste here because its too long. Just in case this might help, I got those two buffer over the network by reading sockets.

The problem is the loop breaks even when both the buffers are the same. To check what is in the buffers, I added the two print statements inside the if statement. And the weird thing is is, the printf statements both print the same value for %c and %02x, but the comparison fails and the loop breaks.

Comment: Out of general interest - does the cast you've added actually change anything?

Comment: I can't spot anything here; perhaps add some code to dump `buffer1` and `buffer2` to disk, store them into `/tmp/1` and `/tmp/2`, and break out `od -x` or `xxd` to try to find the problem?

Comment: How do you know the break exits the loop?  What's the value of i when it exits?  Why not use memcmp?

Comment: i forgot to add the cast in this post which was there in my code. so i edited the post. i havent tried running the code without the cast though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>(Disclaimer: I'm not a C/++ expert)</sub>

It seems to me like the data is changing while you're looking at it. Two quick questions come to mind:

1. If you run this in the debugger, and go over the loop step-by-step, does it still happen? If it doesn't, then I strongly suspect my second question will lead you to the answer.
2. Is the read operation asynchronous? It seems like data is still being read while you're inside the for loop, meaning you didn't wait for the read to finish.

Comment: i think your 2nd point was the issue. the buffers in the code i posted, i got them directly by reading the network. i copied from those buffers into temporary buffers and compared those. and that solved the problem.

Comment: Excellent. Make sure that you always wait until the operation is complete before you try to access the data; usually there's either a method you should call that waits for it to be finished or a callback you can sign up that will happen once it is finished.

Comment: btw the read operation is not asynchronous. the sockets are blocking. so i guess the problem is due to slow buffer management by the OS at the kernel level.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I see is a timing issue.  If they are not the same on the if statement and they are the same on the print statement someone changed them in between.